# Codeigniter CLI shows nothing on library autoloading

Tags: php, codeigniter, command-line-interface

I started with this [codeigniter example](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html), but it doesn't work for me.

When I set a library (says database or session) and I type on CLI

```
php index.php tools message
```

it simply doesn't echo anything. Otherwise if i try to load database library directly on tools class, it returns an error:

```
Unable to load the requested class: database
```

I've looked at other posts but i haven't found any solution. Can somebody help me?

Comment: do some simple `php -r "echo 'Hello.'"`  command works

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved updating to CodeIgniter 3

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the autoload.php file (Codeiginiter 2)

```
if (! empty ($_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'])) {
$autoload ['libraries'] = array ('database', 'session', 'tank_auth', 'permission');
} else {
$autoload ['libraries'] = array ();
}
```